# How can i SELECT rows that continue with [ or are equal to a list of values

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I need to get all records from a table that match  given map names but also those that continue with **[** after the given name
I tried doing this:

```
SELECT route FROM table WHERE route REGEXP 'map_name1|map_name2'
```

The problem is if a map exists with name like **map_name1_version2** it will also return that, but it needs only to return for example **map_name1** and **map_name1[route]**

Edit:

Done it like this

```
SELECT route FROM table WHERE route REGEXP '^map_name1$|mapname1\\[|^map_name2$|mapname2\\['
```

Comment: What about `WHERE route IN ("map_name1", "map_name1[route]")` ?

Comment: Routes are different for each map can be [easy] [hard] or whatever, when it doesn't have brackets it is looked at as [normal] route

Comment: What about something like  `SELECT route FROM table WHERE route = 'map_name1' OR route LIKE 'map_name1[%'`?

Comment: Please provide a short list of strings that should match and a short list of strings that should not match.

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE this way:

```
SELECT route FROM table WHERE route LIKE "map_name1" OR route LIKE "map_name1%" ;
```

OR

```
SELECT route FROM table WHERE route LIKE "map_name1" OR LIKE "map_name1" AND route LIKE "%map_name2%" ;
```